# helper functions in jasmine standalone

Tags: javascript, jasmine, helper

I have a Spec file unit testing a bunch of methods. In the same file I have helper functions. Is there a way to move the helper functions to a separate file with jasmine standalone and vanilla js?

```
  describe('#formatDateAndTime', () => {
    it('formats the date and time as per the requirements', () => {
      expect(till._formatDateAndTime()).toEqual(timeAndDate());
    });
  });

  function timeAndDate () {
    let today = new Date();
    return [today.getFullYear() + '.' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '.' +
    today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() +
    ':' + today.getSeconds()];
  }
```

how can I move timeAndDate() function to a helper file

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jasmine standalone, you link to all your scripts in an html file — let's call that tests.html. Let's say your test cases are in Tests.js, and you put your helpers in TestUtils.js.

Here's what you can do in that HTML file:

**tests.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tests</title>
        
        <!-- Jasmine -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-3.3.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-3.3.0/jasmine.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-3.3.0/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-3.3.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-3.3.0/boot.js"></script>

        <!-- All scripts you want to test -->
        <script src='MyCoolProgram.js'></script>

        <!-- Specs -->
        <script src='TestUtils.js'></script>
        <script src='Tests.js'></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Then, simply open that file in a browser, and you should be able to see your tests running as required.

**Careful!** You must put TestUtils.js *before* Tests.js if you want Tests.js to call TestUtils.js helper methods. This is because in HTML, statically included scripts are injected in the order they appear in the file.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, so rather than ending the file name with Spec I would name it TestUtils.js? is that what you mean? and I can move all my helper functions in the TestUtils.js file as shown in my example above?

Comment: You can name the files almost anything you want really, but the important part is to include the script with your helper functions before the script with your test cases.